# How to compare two columns value in excel?

Tags: excel, comparison

I have over 100k rows of data like below:

```
ALLA,ALLA,"Company1, Inc.","Company1, Inc.",PSA,PSA,1,1,FALSE,FALSE
BCCO,BCCO,"Company2, Inc.","Company2, Inc.",PSB,PSB,1,1,FALSE,FALSE
CTTP,CTTP,"Company3, Inc.","Company3, Inc.",PSC,PSC,1,1,FALSE,FALSE
CMMZ,CMMZ,"Company4, Inc.","Company4, Inc.",PSD,PSD,1,1,FALSE,FALSE
```

I want to know how to figure if data in column 1 is the same as column 2, column 3 as column 4 and so on. How could I do that in excel?

Following Cory's formula, I found that I can compare whole columns using:

```
=if(A:A=B:B, "yay", "aww")
```

Problem is I have a header in the file:

```
c - symbol, symbol, c - companyname,    companyname,    c - tradingvenue,   tradingvenue,   c - tierrank,   tierrank,   c - iscaveatemptor, iscaveatemptor
```

Shouldn't this cause A:A=B:B to be false?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions. You may have better luck over at [su].

Comment: @Cory i was planning on doing this in python, but it's not been nice today.

Comment: Well in Excel formulas it should be easy. In a new column, a formula to check might look like `=IF(A1=B1,"They match!","No :(")`

Comment: @Cory i have over 100k rows, surely there is a better formula than a#=b#

Comment: @Cory second thing i need is to know how many rows actually matched

Comment: @yaojiang Dirty solution but you can put the result of "does it match or not?" in an adjacent column. If it matches, 1 ; if not, 0. Then at the bottom of this new column, you just make a total of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this:

```
   |  A  |  B  |
---+-----+-----+
 1 |  X  |  X  |
---+-----+-----+
 2 |  Y  |  Y  |
---+-----+-----+
 3 |  Z  |  Z  |
```

The formula `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A3=B1:B3))` will tell you how many times the `A` value matches the `B` value.

You should get `3` as a result here. If, for example, you change `B3` to `Q` then it will give you `2`.

To do this on two columns without specifying the end of the range, try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A=B:B),--(LEN(A:A)>0))
```

Comment: this was what i was looking for, thanks! now one last thing to bug you with, how do i make it go from A1:(end of column A)? and B so on. i tried to use counta(A:A) but doesnt seem to work. also trying =INDEX(B:B, COUNTA(B:B)), it gives me the value not the actual index.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Excel since 1991, and unless you want to write a VB macro, I think the best way is to do the simple IF statement suggested in the comments. If you need to test several columns at once, which is what your question suggests, then I'd do

```
=IF(AND(A1=B1,C1=D1,E1=F1,G1=H1),0,1)
```

Fill that formula down the column and then you'll be able to

1. instantly count the number of rows that don't match
2. with a data-filter, select all the rows which have a '1', so you'll be able to examine the rows that don't match